# What do we do about reporting vandalism?

Tags: support

After looking at recent "edits" by [Gay Guy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/56764/gay-guy) all it showed was vandalism and just destroying the site. How should we report users like this. I don't think posting to meta every time is appropriate but I had to ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Report it as spam (or reject suggested edits as vandalism) and move on.

A mod or a cadre of 20kers will be along presently to delete the content.

Comment: "*Report it as spam*" This seems to not be advised by the top-voted answer in the "[What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/162827)" MSO post (part of the FAQ), which suggests that "*A post should be marked as spam **ONLY** when it contains an unsolicited advertisement.*" Should posts that are vandalism (not necessarily spam) be flagged as spam, or for closing/'not an answer'?

Comment: I think you mean "flag it as offensive"? That will have the same priority in the mod queue, and has a similar auto-delete function with enough of them.

Comment: @galacticninja The two flag types are functionally identical. The important part is that one of them be picked consistently, as once 6 flags of the same type are accrued, the spam/offense is handled automagically, same as if a Mod swung by.

Comment: @RavenDreamer They're not functionally identical. Spam flags auto-delete in 3, offensive in 6. Spam flagging data is also collected by the system for potential future anti-spam measures, so we're strongly discouraged from adding false data to that.

Answer (score 3):

If it's repeated by a user and they haven't been dealt with for whatever reason, flag one of their posts with a custom explanation and point out the pattern.  In addition, or otherwise, do as Raven says.